# Using notifications or listeners with protocols and delegates (VIPER architecture)

Tags: ios, notifications, network-programming, viper-architecture

I am creating a chat application and I have a listener set up that listens for new messages broadcasted by users. The listener starts in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. Normally in Viper, UI action happens in the *View*, the *Presenter* gets notified and calls an *Interactor function* which does some sort of network/local logic and passes it back to the Presenter which then updates the View.
How does my listener fit into all that?
How is my View notified whenever a new message is received?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a multicast mechanism som multiple modules/views can attach and receive events.

On the VIPER side you're likely to have a root VIPER module/object that creates children. The listener object you create can be passed to child modules that can attach/detach to the listener as required.